# Usage of “just”: with the meaning of "barely". Could "just" mean someone almost "made it" but didn't ultimately?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Suppose that there was an test, each of the students were given a percentage, maybe 100, maybe 85, maybe 61, maybe 60, maybe 59, grade that is equal or greater than 60 would be marked as passed.

When Tom say:"I **barely** passed the test." I understand he got 60, or more.

When Tom say:"I **just** passed the test." Does that mean the same thing? If he said that **sadly**, is it reasonable to conclude that he got a grade less than 60?

Comment: If you _only just_ do something, you succeed by a very small margin. This is almost a duplicate of your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Just” is by far the more ambiguous word.

It could refer to the passing grade, then meaning:

> I just passed, [but barely so].

It could also have a temporary meaning:

> I just left the exam room and passed.
>   - In the specific situation: ...but am not content with the grade,hence the sad facial expression.
>   - Without facial clues: No information about the speaker’s results or grades are implied.

I would not understand “just passed” as “failed”, though. That would contradict “passed”. If the speaker said “I just *took* the test”, the usage is clearly temporal, but doesn’t necessarily imply they passed.